# Authenticity token only gets set after form submission in React component which throws an error in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, reactjs

I have a form in a React component that only sets the authenticity token after the first form submission after logging in. These are the steps I follow.

1. Home page is a login form which I use to log in. The session gets set so you are logged into the app. You can close your browser and come back and still be logged in.
2. Go to sign up for a class, or create a quiz, which are both form POST submissions.
3. Invalid authenticity token error.
4. Hit the back button, all fields are still filled in.
5. Press submit and it goes through.

Any idea how to set it the first time around?

Application controller is

```
def current_user
  @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
end
```

and the controller code for log in is

```
def create
    @user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])
    # If the user exists AND the password entered is correct.
    if @user && @user.authenticate(params[:password])
    # Save the user id inside the browser cookie. This is how we keep     the user
    # logged in when they navigate around our website.
    session[:user_id] = @user.id
    if @user.type == 'Student'
        redirect_to student_path(@user.id)
    elsif @user.type == 'Instructor'
        redirect_to instructor_path(@user.id)
    end
  else
    redirect_to login_path
  end
end
```

Comment: The authenticity token is per session. You should add `reset_session` to the top of your create (login) action to avoid session fixation. Also ensure that the csrf token is not cached. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#csrf-countermeasures

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I noticed you are using Rails which has a

```
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
```

which should automatically put session variables in the header for you if you set your sessions up correctly. Well React loads with out setting you "token-value" so you should grab it out of the header like so..

```
getInitialState: function() {
    return {token: ''}
},
componentDidMount: function(e) {
    this.setState({token: $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content')})
},
```

and this will make sure the component loads and sets the state as the token value. There you can go on and add

```
<input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value={this.state.token} />
```

to your form and go on about your day.